# Can I find a GitHub commit using this data?

Tags: python, git, github

I've been asked to provide a GitHub repo URL for hundreds of packages using only two bits of information. It looks as if I might be able to do this programmatically, but I need some help figuring out how.

I could just take the base URL given, then manually go to the commit history, and provide a link to there, but I think I can do better. I think the data contains a version, date, and maybe a shortened sha.

Here is an example of the two bits of information given:

```
github.com/shurcooL/reactions
```

```
v0.0.0-20181222204718-145cd5e7f3d1
```

Is there a way to programmatically lead me to the URL for this commit? If so I'd end up writing something in python to work down the list and generate URLs to dump to a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this to extract the shortened github hash, append it to the base URL for commits, then write to a CSV file:

```
from csv import writer

BASE_URL = 'https://github.com/shurcooL/reactions/commit/'

github_data = ['v0.0.0-20181222204718-145cd5e7f3d1']

# open file for writing
with open('github-commit-urls.csv', mode='w', newline='') as f:
    csv_writer = writer(f)
    for data in github_data:

        # split by '-' dash to extract three pieces of data
        release, date, commit_hash_short = data.split('-')

        # write url to file
        csv_writer.writerow([BASE_URL + commit_hash_short])
```

Which will dump the following URL to `github-commit-urls.csv`:

```
https://github.com/shurcooL/reactions/commit/145cd5e7f3d1
```